# How to find Node with the most similarities Neo4j

Tags: database, encryption, neo4j, cypher

I have a list of garages and the cars that they provide:

```
    Store1: [Mazda, Ford, Porsche, VW, Nissan, Opel, Toyota, Seat, Volvo]
    Store2: [Porsche, Honda, Toyota, Audi]
    Store3: [Opel, Toyota, Volvo, Porsche, Kia, Mazda, Seat]
    Store4: [VW, Honda, Bentley, Alfa, Chevrolet, Subaru, Tesla]
    Store5: [Suzuki, VW, Nissan, Ferrari, Maserati, Jag]
    Store6: [Jag, Kia, Seat, Bentley, Alfa, Chevrolet, Ferrari, Mini]
```

I have to find the store which has the most similar options compared to Store 1. How would you structure a cypher to find similarities between nodes?

Comment: Please share the data model (nodes, relationships) of your database. Thanks.

Comment: Data model like above - (s:Store)-[r:INSTOCK]->(b:Brand)

Comment: Thanks Yurty. Im sure Store and Brand nodes has a property named, name.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Your node Store must have a property name, like name: "Store 1", etc.
> 2. Ensure that you installed the data science plugin. If not, follow the installation [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/installation/)
> 3. Below query is based on 'jaccard' similarity algorithm. If you want more about other similarity algorithms, see [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/algorithms/node-similarity/#algorithms-node-similarity)

a. Get all store(s) with stocks of these car brands
b. Collect the data as store items and car brands as categories
c. Compute the jaccard similarity index and return only for a store named: 'Store 1'

```
MATCH (s:Store)-[r:INSTOCK]->(b:Brand)
WITH {item:id(s), categories: collect(id(b))} AS userData
WITH collect(userData) AS data
CALL gds.alpha.ml.ann.stream({
   data: data,
   algorithm: 'jaccard'
 })
 YIELD item1, item2, similarity
 WITH  gds.util.asNode(item1).name AS Store1, gds.util.asNode(item2).name AS StoreX, similarity WHERE Store1 = 'Store 1'
 RETURN  Store1, StoreX, similarity
 ORDER BY StoreX
```

If you want to compute it manually, then the jaccard similarity index of Store 1 to Store X (where X is any store # > 1) is the number of common car brands between Store 1 and Store X and divided by the number of total unique car brands of Store 1 plus Store X.  For example; Store1 to Store2 is 2/11 or 0.1818 since there are 2 common brands (Porsche and Toyota) and Store1 plus Store2 is 11 unique brands.